# Teaching polarisation formula

Tags: teaching

When teaching about Hilbert spaces, one begins with a polarisation formula, which allows us to reconstruct the scalar product from the norm:
$$\langle u,v\rangle=\frac14(\|u+v\|^2-\|u-v\|^2+\imath\|u+\imath v\|^2-\imath\|u-\imath v\|^2).$$
Is there a good reason to choose this formula instead of the more symmetric one
$$\langle u,v\rangle=\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}e^{\imath\theta}\|u+e^{\imath\theta}v\|^2d\theta,$$
or the shortest one (here $\jmath=e^{2\imath\pi/3}$)
$$\langle u,v\rangle=\frac13(\|u+v\|^2+\jmath\|u+jv\|^2+\bar\jmath\|u+\bar\jmath v\|^2) \qquad?$$

Comment: What is $j$ and what is $\jmath$?

Comment: Isn't the answer to your question the same as the answer to "well, where do you want to go with this?"  Sometimes you just want to get the job done, minimally.  Sometimes you want to set people up for further developments of one shape or another.

Comment: There might be some point in teaching a symmetric or shortest polarization formula if the formula was likely to be used a lot in actual computations.  But as far as I am aware, what is mainly used is the **existence** of the formula, i.e. the fact that the inner product is determined by the norm.  Thus a typical application is showing that a linear isometry must be unitary.  Cases where you actually want to compute an inner product from norms are not so common, and when they do arise the norms that you know are unlikely to be those that appear in the formula.

Answer (score 22):

To me it seems most natural to show that the norm determines the scalar product via the two formulas
$$\Vert u + v \Vert^2 = \Vert u \Vert^2 + \Vert v \Vert^2 + 2\mathrm{Re}\langle u, v \rangle$$ 
and 
$$\mathrm{Im} \langle u, v \rangle = \mathrm{Re}\langle u, -iv \rangle.$$
Both of these are immediately obvious, in a way the polarization identities are not (IMO).

Answer (score 18):

The polarization formula carries over to algebraic settings not directly involving real and complex numbers. Let $L/K$ be a quadratic Galois extension, where the nontrivial element of ${\rm Gal}(L/K)$ is denoted with an overline: $\overline{\alpha}$ for $\alpha \in L$. Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional $L$-vector space [edit: as nfdc23 points out, finite-dimensionality is not needed] and $B \colon V \times V \rightarrow L$ be a Hermitian form relative to the extension $L/K$: it is $K$-bilinear, $B(cv,w) = cB(v,w)$ and $B(v,cw) = \overline{c}B(v,w)$ for $c\in L$, and $B(w,v) = \overline{B(v,w)}$. Set $Q \colon V \rightarrow L$ by $Q(v) = B(v,v)$. Can we reconstruct the two-variable function $B$ from the single-variable function $Q$?

Since
$$
Q(v+w) = Q(v) +Q(w) + B(v,w) + B(w,v),
$$
replacing $w$ with $-w$ gives
$$
Q(v-w) = Q(v) +Q(w) - B(v,w) -B(w,v),
$$
so subtracting and dividing by $2$ (if we are not in characteristic $2$) gives us 
$$
\frac{Q(v+w)-Q(v-w)}{2} = B(v,w) + B(w,v).
$$
To get a formula having only $B(v,w)$ on the right, pick $c \in L$ such that $\overline{c} \not= c$. Then
$$
Q(v+cw) = Q(v) +c\overline{c}Q(w) + \overline{c}B(v,w) + cB(w,v),
$$
and
$$
Q(v+\overline{c}w) = Q(v) +\overline{c}cQ(w) + cB(v,w) + \overline{c}B(w,v)
$$
so
$$
Q(v+cw) - Q(v+\overline{c}w) = (\overline{c}-c)(B(v,w) - B(w,v))
$$
and thus
$$
\frac{Q(v+cw) - Q(v+\overline{c}w)}{\overline{c}-c} = B(v,w) - B(w,v).
$$
Since we have formulas for $B(v,w)+B(w,v)$ and $B(v,w)-B(w,v)$, by averaging (if we are not in characteristic $2$), 
$$
\frac{Q(v+w) - Q(v-w)}{4} + 
\frac{Q(v+cw) - Q(v+\overline{c}w)}{2(\overline{c}-c)} = B(v,w).
$$
When $L = \mathbf C$, $K = \mathbf R$, $B(v,w) = \langle v,w\rangle$, $Q(v) = ||v||^2$, and $c = i$ this recovers the classical polarization formula.  If in the same setting we take $c = j = e^{2\pi i/3}$, then we get a polarization formula that is different from the one you wrote down with $j$, but it fits into the *general pattern* described above. Since I showed how the usual polarization formula extends to the general case outside of characteristic $2$ (certainly an integration formula does not), that classical formula is not really specific to the choice $c = i$, but your version using $j$ seems specific to the choice $c=j$ since you are dividing through by $3$. I am not persuaded that a formula using $3$ terms instead of $4$ terms is genuinely simpler: the $4$-term polarization formula is essentially the result of averaging a few times. (Most people, whether by habit or otherwise, would prefer to think of $\mathbf C$ as $\mathbf R + \mathbf R{i}$ rather than as $\mathbf R + \mathbf R{j}$ for both geometric and algebraic reasons, e.g., $\overline{a+bj} = a-b-bj$ for real $a$ and $b$.)

What happens if we are using a Hermitian form in characteristic $2$? Division by $2$ in the classical polarization formula or its generalization above breaks down if we try to reconstruct $B$ from $Q$ in characteristic $2$. We can show $Q$ determines $B$ by the following argument that is valid in all characteristics: for $v$ and $w$ in $V$, and $c \in L$, we have 
\begin{eqnarray*}
Q(cv+w) & = & c\overline{c}Q(v) + Q(w) + B(cv,w) + B(w,cv) \\
& = & c\overline{c}Q(v) + Q(w) + cB(v,w) + \overline{B(cv,w)} \\
& = &  c\overline{c}Q(v) + Q(w) + {\rm Tr}_{L/K}(cB(v,w)).
\end{eqnarray*}
Therefore, when $v$ and $w$ are fixed in $V$, the function $f_{v,w} \colon L \rightarrow K$ given by 
$f_{v,w}(c) = Q(cv+w) - c\overline{c}Q(v) - Q(w)$ is completely determined by $Q$ and it is also $K$-linear since it equals ${\rm Tr}_{L/K}(cB(v,w))$. For a quadratic Galois extension $L/K$, each $K$-linear mapping $L \rightarrow K$ looks like $f(x) = {\rm Tr}_{L/K}(xy)$ for a unique $y \in L$ (this could be shown directly, or it is a consequence of non-degeneracy of the trace-pairing $L \times L \rightarrow K$, where $\langle x,y\rangle \mapsto {\rm Tr}_{L/K}(xy)$). Thus $B(v,w)$ is the unique number $y$ in $L$ such that $Q(cv+w) - c\overline{c}Q(v) - Q(w) = {\rm Tr}_{L/K}(cy)$ for all $c \in L$. There is no need for any polarization formula.

[Edit: I realized after writing this up that I wrote something essentially like this a few years ago on math.stackexchange: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/425173/derivation-of-the-polarization-identities]

Comment: That's a great answer.

Comment: Given the motivation coming from Hilbert spaces, it seems worth noting that the hypothesis at the outset that $V$ is finite-dimensional over $L$ is never used in these arguments.

Answer (score 7):

It works for real Hilbert spaces if we remove two last terms. For two other formulas the real counterpart is not clear.